# Array_filter in the context of an object, with private callback

Tags: php, callback, array-filter

I want to filter an array, using the array_filter function. It hints at using call_user_func under water, but does not mention anything about how to use within the context of a class/object.

Some pseudocode to explain my goal:

```
class RelatedSearchBlock {
  //...
  private function get_filtered_docs() {
    return array_filter($this->get_docs(), 'filter_item');
  }

  private filter_item() {
    return ($doc->somevalue == 123)
  }
}
```

Would I need to change `'filter_item'` into `array($this, 'filter_item')` ? Is what I want possible at all?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Yes:

```
return array_filter($this->get_docs(), array($this, 'filter_item'));
```

See the [documentation for the `callback` type](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Comment: Great info!  If you are using static methods you will have to pass in the class name with the filter function. To do this you can replace `array($this, 'filter_item')`  with `array(__CLASS__, 'filter_item')`.

Comment: Will the filter_item() method be called on the object that calls array_filter(), or on each object in $this->get_docs()?

Comment: @Arild Essentially, `$this->filter_item($doc)` will be called for each item returned from `get_docs()`.

Comment: all i'm reading is deceze php answers today, thank god you're on this site man, seriously..