# PHP nested function gives 'Using $this when not in object context' error

Tags: php

I am trying to filter an array using the built-in `array_filter` function. According to the examples in PHP manual, I have to provide the name of the callback function. So, here is what I tried:

```
// This function is a method 
public function send($user_id, $access, $content, $aids)
{
    // check if user is allowed to see the attachments
    function is_owner($var)
    {
        return $this->attachment_owner($var, $user_id);
    }

    $aids = implode(';', array_filter(explode(';', $aids), 'is_owner'));
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

> **Fatal error:** Using $this when not in object context in filename line number.

How to solve this?

Comment: What's your PHP version?

Comment: Use anonymous functions: array_filter(..., function($var) { ... }); (Sorry, didn't really understand the problem first.)

Comment: $this is no longer within scope. Out of curiosity, why make a nested function here and not just a private function in the class?

Comment: The "nested" function ends up in the global scope; you can't use `$this` inside of it.

Comment: i have similar issue, but i can't make it anonymous because it is used many times. and i don't want it to be a method because it's only relevant to one specific method. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using PHP > 5.4.0, you could create an [anonymous function](http://docs.php.net/functions.anonymous) and even use *$this*:

```
public function send($user_id, $access, $content, $aids)
{   
    // check if user is allowed to see the attachments
    $is_owner = function ($var)
    {
        return $this->attachment_owner($var, $user_id);
    }
    $aids = implode(';', array_filter(explode(';', $aids), $is_owner));
```

Nevertheless I would go with tim's solution because it is cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid using the nested function by making it a member of your class

```
... inside a class
function is_owner($var)
{
    return $this->attachment_owner($var, $user_id);
}

public function send($user_id, $access, $content, $aids)
{
// check if user is allowed to see the attachments


$aids = implode(';', array_filter(explode(';', $aids), array($this, 'is_owner')));
...
```

References:

[What are nested functions for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415969/what-are-php-nested-functions-for)

[Array_filter in the context of an object, with private callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239510/array-filter-in-the-context-of-an-object-with-private-callback)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use anonymous functions:

```
$aids = implode(';', array_filter(explode(';', $aids), function($var) { return $this->attachment_owner($var, $user_id); }));
```